# Writing a list with different levels of importance

Tags: commas, lists

The following sentence has a list with three levels of importance with each level having a list of items.

1. Common carbonate minerals, mainly calcite and dolomite, to a lesser extent ankerite, and in few cases siderite, magnesite, or rhodochrosite, are reported as the principal constituents of carbonate rocks and are the base of the classification model.

Does 'to a lesser extent' and 'in a few cases' need to be set off by commas? I find that this makes the list more confusing.

2. Common carbonate minerals, mainly calcite and dolomite, to a lesser extent, ankerite, and, in few cases, siderite, magnesite, or rhodochrosite, are reported as the principal constituents of carbonate rocks and are the base of the classification model.

I have modified it many times but am unable to reduce its 'clunkyness'. Here are some of my attempts:

3. The classification model is based on the principal constituents of carbonate rocks; mainly calcite and dlolomite, to a lesser extent ankerite, and, in few cases, siderite, magnesite, and rhodochrosite.
4. The principal constituents of corbonate rocks are common carbonates, mainly calcite and dolomite, to a lesser extent ankerite, and in few cases siderite, magnesite, and rhodochrosite. These are the base of the classification model.

Are there any suggestions? What are the gramatic rules when using 'to a lesser extent' or other indicators of importance in a list?

Comment: Common carbonate minerals (mainly calcite and dolomite; to a lesser extent ankerite; and in few cases siderite, magnesite, and rhodochrosite) are reported as the principal constituents of carbonate rocks, and are the base of the classification model. Comma overload is near to being ungrammatical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Writers Stack Exchange here: http://writers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use semicolons for this; you can use commas for subdivisions. I'd also change the order a bit, to stick the list at the end. I've used a variety of punctuation marks, which I think gives greater clarity (hope no-one disagrees).

> The principal constituents of carbonate rocks (the base of the classification model of common carbonate minerals) are reported as: mainly calcite and dolomite; to a lesser extent ankerite; and in few cases siderite, magnesite, or rhodochrosite.

Semicolons in lists:

> complicated lists.
>
> The semicolon can be used to sort out a complicated list containing
>   many items, many of which themselves contain commas.
>
> Have a look at this example:
>
> In the meeting today we have Professor Wilson, University of Barnsley,
>   Dr Watson, University of Barrow in Furness, Colonel Custard,
>   Metropolitan Police and Dr Mable Syrup, Genius General, University of
>   Otago, New Zealand.
>
> In a situation such as this, only the mighty semicolon can unravel the
>   mess.
>
> In the meeting today we have Professor Wilson, University of Barnsley;
>   Dr Watson, University of Barrow in Furness; Colonel Custard,
>   Metropolitan Police and Dr Mable Syrup, Genius General, University of
>   Otago, New Zealand. - *[University of Bristol - Improve your writing](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_05.htm)*